# Changing text of editor for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, vs-extensibility

I'm trying to create a cool extension where I want to do something like below.

Once you have my extension installed, It will get the current line code of visual studio editor when you press some shortcut and then add something at the end of a current line of code.

P.S. I'm not building any analyzer I'm creating a productivity extension which will help people increase their productivity.

I have already gone through the MSDN documentation available for that but I'm really confused which one I should use. See the below link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885474.aspx

Can anybody who has created an extension guide me.

Comment: I guess you're not using VIM. Otherwise, press 'A.' with VsVim.

Comment: See I am not using any extension I want to create the extension.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Info on how to program the shortcut? On how to change the line of code?